# Is that possible to post image with instagram API from custom android app?

Tags: java, android, instagram

**I m looking for a solution to post image to instagram using API  in a custom android application, but not found out while searching through google, can any body tell me some hack, to do this...**

Answer (score 0):

Instagram does not support posting images through their API.